# How can I load content via ajax and create a slidedown effect?

Tags: jquery

JQuery:

```
$.get('/file.php', function(html)
{
    $('#lists li.product:first').before(html).slideDown('slow');
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="lists">
    <li class="name">Name:</li>
    <li class="product">Product 1</li>
</ul>
```

Everything works fine, except for the slidedown effect.

The content gets inserted right before the first `li.product`, but it doesn't look like it's sliding down right behind the `li.name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$.get('/file.php', function(html)
{
    $('#lists li.product:first').before(html);

    $('#lists li.product').hide().slideDown('slow');
});
```

That seems to work for me now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide it

```
 $('#lists li.product:first').hide().before(html).slideDown('slow');
```

first